# Htaccess Redirect from sub domain to new domain but also redirect index to sub directory

Tags: .htaccess

I'm redirecting sub domains (with an htaccess in each sub domain) to a new domain but I want to redirect the index page to a sub-directory on the new domain.

`subdomain.example.com/index.php` to `example.com/folder/index.php`

- Thats for the Index page only for the rest of the subdomain

`subdomain.example.com` to `example.com`

- Thats for all the content pages and Not the Index page.

I can't get both to redirect at same time. Is there a way ?

Comment: gud way, but, what i understand that is you are try to redirect all domains form one file mean index file. Try to follow my instruction, may be it helpful to you.

Comment: hm still not having any luck, i tried this RewriteEngine on Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ebay-de.dcemu.co.uk$ RewriteRule (.*)$ dcemu.com/$1 [R=301,L] RewriteRule ^(index)$ dcemu.com/ebay-auctions.php [R=301,L,NC] this works if i want to redirect a content page ie ebay-de.dcemu.co.uk/… it changes correctly but the index page doesnt go to the url im trying to send it to, first time with htaccess, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews

# handles http redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles http redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/feed?v=$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]

# handles https redirect non sub-dir
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.anotheriste.com/$1 [R=301,L,QSA,NE]
R=301 will redirect with https status 301
```

L will make last rule

NE is for no escaping query string

QSA will append your existing query parameters

$1 is your REQUEST_URI

Comment: hm still not having any luck, i tried this                                                    RewriteEngine on Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews


 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ebay-de.dcemu.co.uk$  
 RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.dcemu.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(index)$ http://www.dcemu.com/ebay-auctions.php [R=301,L,NC]                       this works if i want to redirect a content page ie http://ebay-de.dcemu.co.uk/-1-csi-dark-motives-nintendo-ds--528532.html it changes correctly but the index page doesnt go to the url im trying to send it to, first time with htaccess, thanks for help.